# Clojure thread sleep between map evaluation

Tags: clojure

I have a block of code I need to execute in Clojure that looks like:

```
    (map function coll)
```

However, I need to *delay* the interval of time between each successive function call. That is, I want to call `function` with the first item, then sleep for 10 seconds, then call with the second item, etc.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This sounds like you probably shouldn't be using `map` here -- it provides a *chunked* sequence, whereas it sounds like you're actually looking for time-sensitive side effects. Frankly, when timing is important, I tend to reach for `core.async`; writing a goroutine that intersperced channel reads with timeout operations would be extremely natural.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you're calling `function` on each element of `coll` for side effects, you probably want to use `doseq` with a sleep in between calls.

Comment: Ah right, a `doseq` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks, Charles and Diego.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, following the discussion in the comments, this is what an implementation using `doseq` would look like wrapped in a neat little function:

```
(defn doseq-interval
  [f coll interval]
  (doseq [x coll]
    (Thread/sleep interval)
    (f x)))
```

And here's how you would call it:

```
(doseq-interval prn (range 10) 1000)
```